# Is Octopath Traveler multiplayer?

Tags: octopath-traveler

The Nintendo Shop on the Switch lists the game's "Number Of Players" as "1 or more". On the computer I navigated to [Nintendo.com](https://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/octopath-traveler-switch#game-info) and it says "to be determined".

Is the game multiplayer or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I know Octopath Traveler is single player only.

There are no multiplayer options on the title screen. While I'm still working my way though the first chapter of each character's story, I haven't seen anything in-game to indicate there is multiplayer either.

Comment: [Here's a source](http://www.gamerevolution.com/guides/405289-octopath-traveler-is-there-co-op-splitscreen-or-online-multiplayer) backing up the idea that the game is definitely only single-player.